# Getting Session Variable In Views -- Django

Tags: django, get, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to assign the GET request value to `symbol` if the user has just filled out the form on the previous page. I can navigate to other pages and request the session variable, but when I go back to the index, it is no longer there.

```
def index(request):


    if 'symbol' in request.GET:
        symbol = request.GET.get('symbol', '')
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol

    elif not request.session.get('symbol', 'none'):

        symbol = request.session['symbol']


    return render(request, 'backtests/earnings.html', {'symbol' : symbol})
```

I know there are a few things wrong with this code, but I really do not know where to take this. As of now, I am getting the error

> local variable 'symbol' referenced before assignment

Comment: checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
def index(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    symbol = request.GET.get('symbol', None)

    if symbol is not None or symbol != "":
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol
    else:
        symbol = request.session['symbol']
    return render(request, 'backtests/earnings.html', {'symbol': symbol})
else:
    redirect to path
```

Comment: Hey Clifton thanks for the response. The problem is that I need to reference the session variable in other views as well. If the if statement does not run through till it creates the session variable, it will be 'none' in the other views.

Comment: you mean if session variable is empty u want to return None in session value?

Comment: No i want the session to be created regardless of if the request is a GET because I need to reference the symbol in other views as well.. Currently with the code you provided me, the other view values return none because I have     symbol = request.session.get('symbol', 'none')     in them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
def index(request):

    if 'symbol' in request.GET:
        symbol = request.GET.get('symbol',' None')
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol

    else:
        symbol = request.session['symbol']
```